# Apache Kylin's fact table is not getting incremental data from hive?

Tags: hadoop, kylin

I am working on apache kylin. I am able to getting incremental data from hive dimension tables into kylin using Restful api (using curl command).But my fact table is not getting incremental data from hive, when i am using curl command.If I am doing manual build in kylin GUI then I am getting incremental data into fact table.I am using curl commands as,

```
/usr/bin/curl -c /home/hdfs/.mozilla/firefox/a7ec5aak.default/cookies.sqlite -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic QURNSU46S1lMSU4 =" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://192.168.1.135:7070/kylin/api/user/authentication

/usr/bin/curl -b /home/hdfs/.mozilla/firefox/a7ec5aak.default/cookies.sqlite -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"startTime":'1425384000000', "endTime": '1488907200000', "buildType":"BUILD"}' http://192.168.1.135:7070/kylin/api/cubes/incident_analytics_cube/rebuild
```

what i have to do for getting fact table incremental data also into kylin using curl command. Please suggest me.

2. In kylin am i able to use join query statement without using fact table?

Comment: please anybody share me how to get incremental data into kylin fact table.

Comment: For 1, check the curl command, the "startTime" should be where the latest segment ends. The new "startTime" must equal to the last "endTime".

Comment: For 2, the joins in your query match what's defined in the model. So start from fact table is usual. Lookup tables can be queried directly too, because their snapshots were taken during build.